# Translating Objective-C to Swift - Error: Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: objective-c, swift, methods, nsstring, boolean

I searched on google and on SO but didn't find any useful help for this issue.
I'm trying to translate this code from objective-c to swift:

```
- (void)metaTitleUpdated:(NSString *)title {
NSLog(@"delegate title updated to %@", title);

NSArray *chunks = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
if ([chunks count]) {
    NSArray *streamTitle = [[chunks objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if ([streamTitle count] > 1) {
        titleLabel.text = [streamTitle objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}
}
```

so far i have translated it to this:

```
func metaTitleUpdated(input: String) {
    println("delegate title updated to \(title)")

    let chunks: NSArray = title!.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    if (chunks.count) {
        let streamTitle = chunks .objectAtIndex(0) .componentsSeparatedByString(";")
        if (streamTitle.count > 1) {
        titleLabel.text = streamTitle.objectAtIndex(1)
        }
    }

}
```

but i always get the error "Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'" in the line: if (chunks.count) {

What does cause this error? Is the rest of the code in swift correct or are there any other errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the answer by myself.

```
func metaTitleUpdated(title: String) {
    var StreamTitle = split(title) {$0 == "="}
    var derRichtigeTitel: String = StreamTitle[1]
  titleLabel.text = derRichtigeTitel
    println("delegate title updated to \(derRichtigeTitel)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`chunks.count` has the type `Int`, but the `if` statement requires a boolean expression.
This is different from (Objective-)C, where the controlling expression of an if statement can have any scalar type and is compared with zero.

So the corresponding Swift code for

```
if ([chunks count]) { ... }
```

is

```
if chunks.count != 0 { ... }
```

Comment: You mean `chunks.count > 0`? :)

Comment: that solved the error thanks. but now i get an error: '[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex' at the line "titleLabel.text = streamTitle.objectAtIndex(1)"

whats the problem with that?

Comment: @EnnioE.Meier: That means that streamTitle is a Swift array and not NSArray. You could try `let streamTitle : NSArray = ...` as you did with the chunks definition. Alternatively, use Swift array indexing.

Comment: i changed the code to this now: 
func metaTitleUpdated(input: String) {
        println("delegate title updated to \(title)")
        
        let chunks: NSArray = title!.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
        if chunks.count != 0 {
            let StreamTitle: NSArray = chunks .objectAtIndex(0) .componentsSeparatedByString("=")
            if (StreamTitle.count > 1) {
            titleLabel.text! = StreamTitle.objectAtIndex(1) as NSString
            }
        }
       
    }

but i get an error while running saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @EnnioE.Meier: this is going from one issue to the next. I have tried to answer your question, but I am not going to translate the entire code for you. Please try to *debug* your problem first. If you look up the error message then you'll find many similar Q&A here in SO. If you cannot solve it then please ask a new question.